# PineScript : Dynamic Alert Message in TradingView

Tags: javascript

Sir,
I tried to use Dynamic Alert Message in my pinescript as below. Info I was setting to received : Price, Volume, Date & Chart Link . If alert triggered, message will send to my telegram and easily to open the chart.

I tried in Forex.
It's working & I received alerts complete with Chart Link ( please refers to attachment ).

But, when I try in KLSE / Malaysia Stock Market or other Stock market. Info I received message not complete. Chart link not working. ( please refer to attachments )

I hope someone can helps me to solve it.

This is part of my pinescript Code for Dynamic Alert Message as advised by TradingView last week.

```
var string tickerId = syminfo.tickerid

buy3 = Gcross1
```

if buy3

```
    msgbuy3= 'Symbol=' + tickerId + ', \nteks SinggangSaham ?
 \n' + 'Price=' + tostring(close) + '\nVolume=' + tostring(volume) +  '\nDate=' + tostring(month)+'/'+tostring(dayofmonth)+'/'+tostring(year) +'\nLink : : https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=' + tickerId + '\n'

alert(message=msgbuy3, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[image]
Comparison Alert received from Forex & KLSE/Stocks market

Comment: Can you please edit your post and use <code> quotes as the code of your post will be more readable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this help here:
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000531021

You can use special placeholders to access variable values in alert’s message. For example, you can create an alert on NASDAQ:AAPL and type in a message box:

> {{exchange}}:{{ticker}}, price = {{close}}, volume = {{volume}}

[Sample pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyhAC.png)

YOu can do the same in the alert message field.

Answer (score 0):

Try change session to regular in your chart setting. Also disable 'Adjust data for dividen' if you got "adjustment":"dividends" within your line

[image: image goes here]